# java.awt.* is not supported by GAE? how to resolve this?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

in app engine , i found it doesn't work, it said that java.awt.image.bufferedImage is not supported by GAE.and java.awt.*, javax.imageio.ImageWriter also are not suppoted by GAE. so can someone tell me how to implement those functions in GAE?

Comment: Two problems here: 1. App Engine isn't for making desktop apps, so doesn't have the Advanced Windowing Tooling (AWT) or Swing installed. 2. You can't write to disk using an App Engine app.

Answer (score 5):

> so can someone tell me how to implement those functions in GAE?

The simple answer is that it is not possible in GAE.

Comment: No idea.  However, it looks like a "code dump" rather than a live project to me.

Answer (score 5):

The Google App Engine has a great built-in **[Images API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/)** for image processing tasks.
For filesystem emulation on the Google App Engine, have a look at **[GAE VFS](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/)**

In short, the way you are trying to accomplish your goal is inconsistent with the design of the App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

If the usual built-in packages aren't available, you could try [Jimi](http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/), which is a pure Java image processing library. It hasn't been updated in the best part of a decade, but it should do the job. No school like the old school.

Comment: As far as i know, it's pure java, so it can be run like any other classes. It doesn't depend on any operating system interfaces like java.net.Socket, java.io.File, etc. I don't know very much about GAE, but i believe that this means it is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

GAE does not support java.awt images. You have to use GAE Image API to work with images. 
Reference: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

This API operates with bytes. The source/destination of your image data can be: post from form, URL connection, DataStore BLOB or BlobStorage.

Answer (score 0):

For some seasons, when you are using external libs already using BufferedImage behind the scenes the GAE's ImageService is useless. I have googled out https://github.com/witwall/appengine-awt but haven't tryed it yet. i believe it is enough to just add the dependency of this lib to the project to make it working.