# java applet in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, applet

is it possible to create a applet  client application in GAE ? i had been browsing for hours and couldnot find whether this is possible... i tried embedding it in the HMTL file also....but it doesnot work...why is tat so?

```
<applet code="myapplet.class"  width="320" height="120">
</applet>
```

and my applet class just contains a hello world display.....the myapplet.java shows the following error :

java.awt.Graphics is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Comment: GAE is for servlets, not applets.

Comment: ya i have an servlet....can i call this servlet from applet??

Comment: In case with HTML, you should put your myapplet.class in folder with your html file. Can you show your applet code?

Comment: in side the body of HTML i have given <applet code="myapplet.java"  width="320" height="120"></applet> the myapplet.java contains : public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }

Comment: when i extend the class...it shows the following error:  Applet is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Comment: Try to use another browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applets are run on the browser, not on the server. Therefore the web server technology is irrelevant - you can store your applet's jar file on GAE, Tomcat, Apache, nginx or any other web server.

Make sure you put the applet's **compiled** code in the public part of the WAR, not under the WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The class file is the compiled code, the java file is the source code

Comment: when i browsed...i just got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513961/java-awt-is-not-supported-by-gae-how-to-resolve-this ....im still not sure if this is possible....

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the difference between *Servlet* and *Applet*. GAE is a servlet container, so it can serve web sites and applications, and as such is similar in functionality to Apache+PHP for example. Applets are mini applications that live in the browser, like flash. In any case, the Applet code does not run on the server, so the existence or none existence of the java.awt package is irrelevant. What are you trying to accomplish?