# java.awt.image. is a restricted class in google application engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I wanted to write an application on Google App Engine + Google Cloud Storage for some images processing. But I stumble upon the following exception:

> java.awt.image.DirectColorModel is a restricted class.

For image processing, I wanted to try out Apache Commons Imaging. My guess is that any libraries for image processing will stumble on similar error, since probably most of them use java.awt.image.* package. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: there is a standard appengine service for basic image processing (resize, rotate, crop, etc) btw

Answer (score 0):

So basically Google AppEngine does not support java.awt.image.* .

However, you can use the Google AppEngine Image API to work with images.

And you can check this link for more details on Image-API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

Btw, similar issue at [java.awt.* is not supported by GAE? how to resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513961/java-awt-is-not-supported-by-gae-how-to-resolve-this)